# Regular expression to extract word after = when word before has certain match

Tags: regex

I have the following string

```
 ; APP=INFA;FldNm=DM_MMC;WrkRunId=197981;WrkNm=wf_DM_MMC_EGAIN;
```

I am trying to get the word after the APP=, in this Case INFA (not including the ;)
But sometimes 'APP' is 'Application' or 'application name'. 
So I need a pattern that would give me the word after '=' when the word before '=' has 'app' in it, not case sensitive?

This one works for APP, but for nothing else

```
(?<=APP=)(.+?\b)
```

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/BOYzSV/1, grab Group 1 value.

Answer (score -1):

This will look for `app`, continue until the next `=`, and capture in group 1 everything until the next word boundary.

```
(?i)(?:app[^=]*=)(\w+)
```

Thanks to [Wiktor Stribiżew’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782209/regular-expression-to-extract-word-after-when-word-before-has-certain-match#comment82525756_47782209) for the `(?i)` strategy and the `(?:…)` simplification.

Comment: This is close, when I run this expression I get `APP=INFA`, I was looking for 'INFA' only

Comment: Why not just `(\w*)` at the end instead of that complicated `(.+?\b)`?

Comment: @dnickless `(\w*)` and `(.+?\b)` aren’t always equivalent, but you’re right, in this case `(\w+)` would be better.

Comment: @user3482393 You can get 'INFA' from the first capturing group `()` of the regex. Depending on your programming language or text editor, this could be accessible as `match[1]`, `$1`, or `\1`. I'm afraid it is impossible to make a regex that matches the app name without needing to use a capturing group. You used `(?<=…)` positive lookbehind in your original regex to accomplish this, but that [only worked because](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind) `app` has a constant number of characters. `(?<=app.+)` will just give an error.